# elem.innerHTML = "<body></body>" isn't working. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
let t=document.createElement('template');

t.innerHTML = "<body></body>"

var E = t.children; // HTMLCollection { length: 0 }

t.innerHTML = "<div></div>"; 
var E = t.children; // HTMLCollection { 0: div, length: 1 }
```

the div is getting parsed but not the body, why the body tag isn't getting parsed ?

I'm using Firefox 99.0.1 on windows 10

Comment: Dynamically adding to a `<template>`? Why?  Well whatever the reason...you need to append, insert, etc the `<template>` to the DOM or a `documentFragment` before you can do anything to it.

Comment: consider `createElement("body")` and `appendChild()`

Comment: Look at these two statements in isolation: `t.innerHTML = "<body></body>";` and `t.innerHTML = "<div></div>";`. The second statement _overwrites_ the HTML that was added in the first statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Template elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-template-element) are not allowed to contain body elements.

The [parsing rules](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody) say that when encountering

> A start tag whose tag name is "body" …  if there is a template element on the stack of open elements, then ignore the token.